# Electromagnetic converters, differentials and integrals

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, electric-circuits, integration

In the context of electromagnetic converters, a converter can be modeled by a system that receives electrical energy and outputs mechanical energy. At some point in my textbook, the authors present the following differential that represents a small change in the co-magnetic energy of the system:

$$ \mathrm dW_\mathrm{cmag} = \sum_{k=1}^n \phi_k di_k$$

where $\phi_k = \phi_k(i_1,i_2,...,i_n)$ the total flux generated by the currents $i_1,...,i_n$ in the $k$th winding/coil that is part of the system.  $W_\mathrm{cmag}$ represents a co-magnetic energy of the system (state function). $\mathrm dW_\mathrm{cmag}$ is then simply a small change in the system's co-magnetic energy. They then do something that I'm not sure I understand, that is how they integrate $dW_\mathrm{cmag}$ in order to get $W_\mathrm{cmag}$:

$$W_\mathrm{cmag} = \int_{0,0,\ldots,0}^{i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_n} \sum_{k=1}^n \phi_k \mathrm di_k$$

1. **I am not sure I understand their bound notation. What does this integral represent?** Is this a vector line integral by any chance? And why not simply take this integral: $\int_{0}^{i_k} \sum_{k=1}^n \phi_k \mathrm di_k$?

   Then they assume that the relation between $\phi_k$ and $i_1,...,i_n$ is linear so that $\phi_k = \sum_{j=1}^{n} L_{kj} i_j$. And because $L_{kj} = L_{jk}$, $\mathrm dW_\mathrm{cmag}$ can be rewritten as

   $$ \mathrm dW_{cmag} = \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\sum_{j=1}^{n} L_{kj} i_j\right) \mathrm di_k = \dfrac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{n} L_{kj} (i_j\mathrm di_k + i_k\mathrm di_j),$$

   and then they integrate to get

   $$ W_\mathrm{cmag}=\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{n} L_{kj} i_k i_j $$
2. **How did they compute this last integral?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct - that integral is indeed a line integral. Writing out $\mathbf i= (i_1,\ldots,i_n)$ and $\boldsymbol\phi = (\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_n)$, you can write out that integral in notation that may be a bit more familiar, or at least more geometrical:
$$
W_\mathrm{cmag}
= \int_{0,0,\ldots,0}^{i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_n} \sum_{k=1}^n \phi_k\mathrm di_k
=\int_\mathbf{0}^\mathbf{i}\boldsymbol\phi\cdot\mathrm d\mathbf i. \tag1
$$
If you've done things right (i.e. if $\boldsymbol\phi= \boldsymbol\phi( \mathbf i)$ is a conservative field) then that integral will be independent of the path, but that doesn't mean that the individual segments
$$\int_{0}^{i_k} \phi_k \mathrm di_k$$
are independent of the values of $i_{k'}$ for $k'\neq k$. The line integral in $(1)$ is notated that way to enforce the correct values of the other currents as you integrate over $i_k$: you can traverse the edges of the hypercube in any order you like, but once you've done the integral over $i_k$, you need to take it at its nonzero final value over the rest of the remaining integrals. (Alternatively, you can take any arbitrary path within or even outside the hypercube, with all currents changing at the same time, but it's the same difference.)

To integrate out that integral, you essentially use the fact that
$$
\int_0^x y\,\mathrm dx = xy
$$
if $x$ and $y$ are independent, whereas if they're the same it's
$$
\int_0^x x\,\mathrm dx = \frac12 x^2.
$$
Putting this in terms of your currents, and to do this in full generality, suppose that you have some arbitrary traversal $s\mapsto \mathbf i(s)$ that starts at $\mathbf 0$ and ends at $\mathbf i(1)$. Then, each individual symmetrized integral reads
$$
\int_0^{\mathbf i} i_j \mathrm d i_k +i_k \mathrm d i_j
= \int_0^{1} \left( i_j(s) \frac{\mathrm d i_k}{\mathrm ds}+i_k(s) \frac{\mathrm d i_j}{\mathrm ds} \right)\mathrm ds.
$$
If $j\neq k$, then the symmetrized product is a total derivative, and the integral is easy:
$$
\int_0^{\mathbf i} i_j \mathrm d i_k +i_k \mathrm d i_j
= \int_0^{1} \left( i_j(s) \frac{\mathrm d i_k}{\mathrm ds}+i_k(s) \frac{\mathrm d i_j}{\mathrm ds} \right)\mathrm ds
= \int_0^{1} \frac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm ds}\left(i_j(s) i_k(s) \right)\mathrm ds
=i_j(1) i_k(1) 
=i_j i_k.
$$
If $j=k$, then there is only one term, and you can integrate it directly:
$$
\int_0^{\mathbf i} i_k \mathrm d i_k +i_k \mathrm d i_k
= \int_0^{1} 2i_k(s) \frac{\mathrm d i_k}{\mathrm ds} \mathrm ds
= \int_0^{1} \frac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm ds}\left(i_k(s)^2 \right)\mathrm ds
=i_k(1)^2
=i_k^2
=i_ji_k.
$$
Either way, the result is the same, and it matches the stated result.